# PM2 cron running every second

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

I'm using the --cron flag to run a job every hour. The issue is as soon as I deploy using pm2 deploy. I see in the logs it's running the job every second.

```
apps: [
    {
        name: "api",
        script: "./index.js",
        autorestart: true
    },
    {
        name: "cron",
        script: "./cron.js --cron '0 * * * *'"
    }
],
```

The cron syntax seems to be correct, am I missing something else?

Comment: What does the script do? Any chance it is restarting itself? Does it work if you do `pm2 start cron.js --cron "0 * * * *"` directly? Does it work if `cron.js` is just a simple `console.log("hello");`-like script?

Comment: I found the solution, since it's a cron script I was ending it with process.exit(0) or process.exit(1) when there's an error, this was causing the script to restart, I added the --no-autorestart flag and it's all good now.

Comment: @MiguelStevens 
Please add your answer and accept it. you saved me countless hours of debugging

Comment: @Mohathealmightycamel It's been a while, did you only add the --no-autorestart? Or also removed the process.exit() lines?

Answer (score 1):

The way to properly create a cronjob with pm2 is:

```sh
pm2 start index.js --no-autorestart --cron "*/15 * * * *" --name "My 15m cron job"
```

If passing arguments is needed then:

```sh
pm2 start index.js --no-autorestart --cron "*/15 * * * *" --name "My 15m cron job" -- --cron-15m
```